# Clarification about finding CDF from PDF

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

The question I have is:

$$f_x(x) = \begin{cases}4x^3 &  0<x<1\\ 0 & otherwise\end{cases}$$

Where I have to find the CDF function of $F_y(y)$ = $y=-log(x)$.

My steps were:

Consider $P(X \le x) = 12x^2$ so:

$P(Y \le y) = P(-log(x) \le y ) = P(X \le e^{-y})$

So the CDF of Y is: $F_Y(y) = 12(e^{-y})^2$.

I'm just a bit confused on the last bit of the CDF steps, do I sub it back into the $P(X \le x) = 12x^2$ or do I do the following where I sub $P(X \le e^{-y})$ into $Y = -log(X) = -log(e^{-y})$ to get $F_Y(y) = -y$

Comment: What is the relationship between $X$ and $Y$?  Your equation $F_y(y)=-\log(x)$ does not make sense.  The left-hand-side is a function of $y$ while the right-hand-side is a function of $x$.  You may also want to use the notation $f_Y(y)$ and $F_Y(y)$.

Comment: $P(X\le x)$ is the integral not the derivative, so $P(X\le x)=x^4$. If $x=1$, the maximum value, then using your formula $P(X\le x)=12$ which contradicts that probabilities should be between zero and one.

Answer (score 1):

$-\log X \leq y$ is same as $X \geq e^{-y}$ (and not $X \leq e^{-y}$)  since  you are multiplying by $-1$.

$P(X \geq e^{-y})=1-e^{-4y}$ so $f_Y(y)=4e^{-4y}$ for $y \geq 0$.